# Where did Chat and Max end up?

Tags: tales-of-eternia

At the end when the core of Seyfert's ring is destroyed the platform that Reid, Farah, Meredy and Keele were on split into 2.

Now given what Keele said about how Inferia and Celestia would drift apart with the ring's destruction and we see Reid and Farah end up on Inferia and after the first credits we see them with Chat saying how they were off to see their friends i assumed that Meredy and Keele ended up on Celestia.

However i didn't see where Chat and Max ended up. yes Chat was shown on Inferia before picking up Ried and Farah but her ship was further upgraded to make the trip between the 2 planets so it doesn't exactly confirm where she ended up.

So where did Chat and Max end up after Seyfert's Ring was destroyed?

Answer (score 1):

> At the end of the story, Chat, along with Reid Hershel and Farah Oersted, prepare to travel to Celestia to visit Keele Zeibel and Meredy.

Taken from [Aselia Wikia](http://aselia.wikia.com/wiki/Chat)

So, it seems to me, that Chat ended up on Celestia, even if it was only for a temporary visit.

> But after his perceived victory against Balir, Max asserts himself as the de facto ruler of Celestia

Taken from [Aselia Wikia](http://aselia.wikia.com/wiki/Max)

Which makes me think, that he would also end up in Celestia. Especially, since it seems his wife wanted to join him again:

> At Jini, the artist tells Reid that she completed her sketchbook and that she can finally offer it to the sea to the childhood friend of her memories. By doing so, she says she can now return to her husband to resume their lives together, revealing herself to be Max's wife, Lesitia.

Also taken from [Aselia Wikia](http://aselia.wikia.com/wiki/Max)